# Rounded NSView in a Transparent Window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm trying to make a transparent NSWindow with a rounded view in there.

I'm trying to have a rounded view with a transparent window.

This is what it looks like now: (see the little dots in the corners)

[image]

Here's another example with the border radius set to 10px (set in NSView drawRect):

[image]

I am using code from this Apple sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Specifically this method in my NSWindow subclass:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag {
    // Using NSBorderlessWindowMask results in a window without a title bar.
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Start with no transparency for all drawing into the window
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        // Turn off opacity so that the parts of the window that are not drawn into are transparent.
        [self setOpaque:NO];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

And this in my NSView subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSBezierPath* thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [thePath appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect:dirtyRect xRadius:3 yRadius:3];
    [thePath fill];
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't try, but what about using QuartzCore, and setting cornerRadius (in CALayer) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the following, where there's a red outline (stroke), but the center area is transparent?

[image]

If so, to achieve that, I used the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)frame {
    frame = NSInsetRect(self.frame, 3.0, 3.0);

    [NSBezierPath setDefaultLineWidth:6.0];

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame
                                             xRadius:6.0 yRadius:6.0];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [path stroke];
}
```

If that's what you're looking for, you can probably use that as a starting point. You'll want to make sure that you inset the `frame` rect one half of the stroke line width, so as to avoid the problem with clipping the corners like you were seeing.

Comment: Thank you! I don't need the center area to be transparent though, it's just a text field. Regardless, this code works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but there is a great class by Matt Gemmell called MAAttachedWindow and can be found here: http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass/

It's a little older but still works great for me when I need to do a 'floating' popup window and configure transparency, border radii, and even add a small arrow for context if desired. I use it all the time.