# Outlining a System Window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I'm trying to outline a window similarly to Mission Control and Exposé.  I've created a custom `NSWindow` that is transparent and has an outline similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007580/rounded-nsview-in-a-transparent-window), but I don't want the user to interact with this window at all.

Is there any way to do this?

Below is my custom NSWindow, which I've been calling with

```
windowOutline = [[WindowOutline alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:1 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:false];
    [windowOutline makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [windowOutline drawRect:rect];
```

---

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super
            initWithContentRect:contentRect
            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
            backing:bufferingType
            defer:flag];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)frame {
    frame = NSInsetRect(self.frame, 3.0, 3.0);

    [NSBezierPath setDefaultLineWidth:6.0];

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame
                                                         xRadius:6.0 yRadius:6.0];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you possibly post some code to accompany your description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already half way there. You need to create a custom window and content view as described [in the answer you've already found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007580/rounded-nsview-in-a-transparent-window). Note that `drawRect:` is in the custom view (which you'll set as your window's `contentView`), *not* in your window subclass. From your code snippet it's not entirely clear if you have set it up that way. You should now have a transparent, outlined window.

You'll then need to:

1. Set the window level `-[NSWindow setLevel:]` one of the constants above `NSNormalWindowLevel`.
2. Make your application an agent app so it doesn't appear in the Dock etc. by setting `LSUIElement` in the Info.plist.
3. Set `ignoresMouseEvents` on the window to `YES`.